# Django - Extending Existing Login Authentication

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

In addition to the normal authentication I just want to add one more condition during login to the admin site. How can extend the existing auth mechanism? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom authentication backend. See the docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend